# Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core in MVC Cannot display data in Grid from a DB context

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I think I'm close.  Its not throwing any errors but its also not displaying any data... Im just trying to get it to display a list of Company Names and Company IDs from my TblCompanyInfo table.

This is my controller:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
        var apptReminderContext = _context.TblCompanyInfos.Include(t => t.AcctType).Include(t => t.CompanyStatus).Include(t => t.OnHoldReason);
        return View(await apptReminderContext.ToListAsync());
        //return View();
    }

    public JsonResult Products_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        DataSourceResult result = _context.TblCompanyInfos.ToDataSourceResult(request,
            model => new TblCompanyInfo
            {
                CompanyId = model.CompanyId,
                CompanyName = model.CompanyName
            });
        return Json(result);
    }
```

and my view...

```
    @model IEnumerable<AppointmentRemindersNetCoreMVC.Models.TblCompanyInfo>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

@using AppointmentRemindersNetCoreMVC.Data
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@addTagHelper *, Kendo.Mvc

@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

       @(Html.Kendo().Grid<AppointmentRemindersNetCoreMVC.Models.TblCompanyInfo>()
        .Name("grid")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Company"))
        .PageSize(20)
        //.ServerOperation(false)
        //.Model(model => model.Id(c => c.CompanyId))
        //.Read("Products_Read", "Company")
        //.Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Company"))
        .Update("UpdateCustomer", "Home")
        .Create("InsertCustomer", "Home")
        .Destroy("DeleteCustomer", "Home"))

        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(product => product.CompanyName);
            columns.Bound(product => product.CompanyId);
        })
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        
    )
```

Also I know that the Products_Read function is being called by the view and I also know that the "result" contains 32 rows of data.  However, nothing is displayed in the grid.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Turns out that json camelcases the return string so the model properties did not match what was returned by json. The solution was to add this line to the Startup.cs file.

```
services.AddControllers()
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
```